# How do I undo a key like NUM7?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

There are a number of NUM keys that show in a 'perfect view'.  After pressing one how do I go back?

Comment: Undo will not revert changes done to the interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an addon for that™

[Stored Views](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/stored_views/) is bundled with blender 2.79. Simply open up the user preferences and enable *Stored Views*.

Now in the 3D view go to the properties region ( <kbd>N</kbd> ) and click the *Initialize* button under the *Store Views* panel (it's probably at the bottom).

Now you can save custom views and go back to them at any time (still no undo support though). Start by clicking the *Save Current* button, you will now have something that looks like this:

[image: stored views interface]

Granted with just one stored view its not to useful. However I labeled the impotent buttons. The Cube button outlined in red is the button to switch to that view. The blue line is highlighting the *Save Current* button which is used to store the current view.

A normal looking screenshot with more views saved:
[image: stored views interface]

The triangle on the indented line is indicating that the 3D view is in the same position as that view. (That feature breaks when using multiple 3D views)

Comment: It may not be exactly what I was looking for, but it will save me having to reload all the time.  So many thanks!  And it brings add-ons to my attention.

Comment: A little tweak:  I found that just doing that the stored views disappear when you exit and restart Blender.  The  fix appears to be to enable I/O in the user prefs for stored views.  Then remember to reload them when starting a new session!

Answer (score 1):

I guess by "perfect view", you mean a view without perspective (aka Orthographic view). You can use NUM5 to switch between Perspective and Ortho.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't about persp/ortho.    I am using the Wikibooks pages and it talks about 'perfect views', using NUM7, NUM1 and NUM3.  But it doesn't say how to undo the view.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't Undo the view manipulations, because Blender don't handle this like a real transformation of the scene, but rather like a UI thing (like scrolling a panel or resizing a window). If you want to save a particular view, you can add a new Camera.